# Carrierwave: Extract image from uploaded file and discard original file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

We're using CarrierWave for file uploads in the project I'm working on. A new requirement came in that addresses a need to upload DICOM files. [DICOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) files contain an image (or images) in addition to lots of other data. Using the [Ruby DICOM](http://dicom.rubyforge.org/) gem, I'm able to extract the images from a file with ease. My problem comes when I try to upload them using CarrierWave.

I want to be able to extract a JPEG from the uploaded file, and store that file instead of the original DICOM file. I tried creating a `version` of the uploaded file like this:

```
version :jpeg, :if => :is_dicom? do
  process :create_jpeg
end

def is_dicom?(file)
  IO.binread(file.to_file, 4, OFFSET) == 'DICM'
end

def create_jpeg
  Rails.logger.debug "self is class #{self.class}"
  dcm = DICOM::DObject.read(file.path)
  image = dcm.image.normalize
end
```

I based my `create_jpeg` method off another `create_thumbnail` method I found which, without its exception handling, would be reduced to:

```
def create_thumbnail(width, height, gravity = 'Center')
  self.resize_to_fill(width, height, gravity)
end
```

I can see in the debug console that the DICOM is being read successfully, but it doesn't actually save the JPEG that would be extracted. Instead, I get my original DICOM and a copy with 'jpeg' added to the front of the filename. How can I tell CarrierWave that I want to store this JPEG I extracted, and not store the original file that I processed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know versions to just that, create a different version of the file to restore later. To prevent this you'd have to overwrite the file with the JPEG.

How about creating a virtual attribute `image_dicom` in your model, extract the JPEG, and then assign that to the `image` attached uploader? Now uploading a file with the `image_dicom` attribute name can be parsed but won't be stored in the database.

You'd have to parse the uploaded file, something Carrierwave does automatically, but I don't think that would be a huge problem. Not sure how that is represented internally, I know it's not a regular `File` object, but shouldn't be to hard to detect and extract the raw data and JPEG.

Edit: Obviously, if you need to parse DICOM files and regular images, this gets a little bit more complex since you'd have to detect the file type and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the manual extraction, you could also use that processor without using versions as far as I know.

This way you can manipulate the file itself as it is uploaded without creating versions. I've never done this, but it seems to be as easy as just doing:

```
process :create_jpeg, :if => :is_dicom?

def is_dicom?(file)
  IO.binread(file.to_file, 4, OFFSET) == 'DICM'
end

def create_jpeg(image)
  directory = File.dirname(current_path)

  # not quite thread safe, generate something unique here
  tmpfile   = File.join(directory, "tmpfile")

  FileUtils.mv(current_path, tmpfile)

  dcm = DICOM::DObject.read(tmpfile)
  image = dcm.image.normalize.write(current_path)

  FileUtils.rm(tmpfile)
end

# replace the extension with jpg
def filename
  super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.jpg'
end
```

Copied and adapted from: http://www.freezzo.com/2010/12/23/create-ffmpeg-processor-for-carrierwave-in-rails-3/ and Carrierwave docs.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kamiel. It seems like I can upload the file as it is uploaded like you said, but I'm not sure how I can tell CarrierWave to store the JPEG that I created from the DICOM. Any idea if that can be done?

Comment: As far as I know you just have to replace the file with the JPEG (in CW or perhaps even on the disk?). You might have to override some defaults like changing the filename to match the jpeg extension. It literally just executes the function specified in process when the file gets uploaded.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm still getting some weird behavior. Although this seems to handle overwriting the old file, it never gets moved from the temp folder to the proper uploads folder. A record is inserted into the database, but no folder is created in my `uploads` directory.